# JMeter non-gui passing UTF-8 parameter

Tags: utf-8, jmeter, command-line-interface

Passing **UTF-8** character to **XML** in **JMeter** from **CLI**. But in **JMeter** not supporting that character. It sends question mark instead of **UTF-8** character. I used `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` this command in **CLI** and make **File Encoding** to **UTF-8** etc set everything **UTF-8**. But still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Content Encoding to UTF-8 on [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request):

[image: Set Content Encoding]

Comment: i already make that setting. And do some settings in _user.properties_

Answer (score 0):

As per [JDK-6584897](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6584897) you need to properly configure your locale to match the character you're sending as Java relies on native libraries which are using locale-specific code pages so unfortunately there is nothing you can do from JMeter perspective (unless you're willing to write some [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) code parsing the arguments in the JSR223 Test Elements)

One possible solution is that using [chcp](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) utility will help

It might be a chance that ticking "Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" will resolve your issue

However if you don't have admin access to your OS settings or doing some I18N/L10N testing and need more than one locale - the only solution I can think of is putting your parameter to [*user.properties* file or an extra .properties file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) or in CSV file and access it using [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

Comment: Thanks. Btw chcp is only working in cli and at the moment when cli passing parameter to xml it appears "?"